# C++ map problem

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

I have a

```
 map<char*, int> labels;
```

thats exhibiting some behavior that I can't wrap my head around at all. For one index it's returning different values for what I'm pretty sure are the same indexes. Heres an example:

earlier in my program, I add an entry as follows:

```
labels[current->u.bj.target->name] = blockNum + 1;
//Test code

    if (blockNum + 1 == 9)
    {
        stringtest = current->u.bj.target->name;
        cout << "Condition Met" << endl;
        testCond = true;
    }
```

later on in my program, I do the following

```
if ((*stringtest) == (*current->u.bj.target->name))
    cout << "Why is this printing the correct val " <<labels[stringtest] << endl;
branchTarget = labels[current->u.bj.target->name];
cout << "Why is this value different" << branchTarget << endl;
```

as you can tell from the cout statements, `labels[stringtest]` returns 9, but `labels[current->u.bj.target->name]` returns 0 despite the fact they both point to the same thing. Can anyone give me an idea whats wrong/how to fix it? I'm almost positive I never put 0 into the map at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem will probably disappear if you replace `map<char*, int>` with `map<string, int>`. That's because comparing two `char*` objects will only compare the pointers, not the characters, whereas comparing two `string` objects will compare the characters.

(Don't forget to `#include <string>`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `current->u.bj.target->name` is a `char*`. So when you write

```
if ((*stringtest) == (*current->u.bj.target->name))
```

you're dereferencing two `char*`s and comparing the `char`s they point to. So you're only comparing the first characters of both strings!

Also, using pointers as keys to a `map` is dangerous if you're not careful. Lookups will only work correctly if you pass a pointer to the *same string*, not to another string that *happens to contain the same characters*. Use `std::string`, like FredOverflow already suggested, if you want the latter behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
((*stringtest) == (*current->u.bj.target->name))
```

compares the first character of the characters contained in the respective arrays. So there's nothing wrong with the map, you're just comparing "apples to oranges". I recommend to replace `std::map< char*, int >` with `std::map< std::string, int >`.

Answer (score 0):

Any type of pointer will be compared (by default) by memory address, so the only way they it will return a match is if the pointers are to the same object. As other people have said, a good way round this is to use a container with a comparison operator (like std::string), or you could overload the compare function which is the third template parameter to a std::map to a class you wrote that dereferences the pointers and compares the values instead